# flutter firebase version solving failed

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies

Because firebase_storage >=2.0.0 depends on firebase_core ^0.3.0 and firebase_auth 0.6.6 depends on firebase_core ^0.2.5+1, firebase_storage >=2.0.0 is incompatible with firebase_auth 0.6.6.
And because no versions of firebase_auth match >0.6.6 <0.7.0, firebase_storage >=2.0.0 is incompatible with firebase_auth ^0.6.6.
So, because store_manager_erp_next depends on both firebase_auth ^0.6.6 and firebase_storage ^2.1.0+1, version solving failed.

I am new in flutter, please help me to solve this issue

```
banner: ^0.1.3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2  

  http: ^0.12.0
    # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  #sqflite: any
  sqflite: ^0.13.0+1
  folding_cell: "^0.1.0"
  flutter_rating: ^0.0.2
  firebase_auth:  ^0.6.6
  firebase_database: ^1.0.5 
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
  fluttertoast: ^2.1.5
  progress_hud: ^1.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^0.3.0
  mongo_dart: ^0.3.4
  google_sign_in: ^3.0.4
  material_search: ^0.2.8
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.1.2
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.2
  flutter_typeahead: ^0.4.1
 # flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
  flutter_firebase_ui: ^0.0.13
  json_serializable: ^2.0.1
  flutter_spinkit: "^3.1.0"
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  flutter_html: ^0.8.2
  #pinch_zoom_image: "^0.2.5"
  #photo_view: ^0.2.0
  splashscreen: ^1.1.0
  #shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  badges: ^0.0.6
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
 firebase_auth:  ^0.6.6
```

to

```
 firebase_auth:  ^0.8.0
```

You might also need to check other dependencies if the constraints are outdated.

You can also use the workaround mentioned in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12627#issuecomment-400037580

```
export FLUTTER_ROOT="/Users/something/flutter"
pub upgrade
```

to get information for what dependencies updates are available.

Comment: Because flutter_firebase_ui 0.0.13 depends on firebase_auth ^0.6.2+1 and no versions of flutter_firebase_ui match >0.0.13 <0.1.0, flutter_firebase_ui ^0.0.13 requires firebase_auth ^0.6.2+1.
So, because store_manager_erp_next depends on both firebase_auth ^0.8.0 and flutter_firebase_ui ^0.0.13, version solving failed.

Comment: flutter_firebase_ui wasn't updated since Oct 25, 2018 and is not compatible with newer firebase package versions. You would need to constrain to versions that are compatible with that package if you want to use it or create an issue in the flutter_firebase_ui repo to make it compatible with latest firebase packages.

Comment: androidx issue occured with changed to 0.8.0

Answer (score 3):

just add this line of code in your pubspec

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: 0.3.0
```

this will override the dependency, and you can use whatever version you want.
you might need to change it the version of the package.

my code example:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  file_picker: ^3.0.0
  hive: ^2.0.0
  hive_flutter: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  path_provider: 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your project to AndroidX . Please see the following documentation for detailed steps on it...

[Migrate to Android X](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Or else, just downgrade the firebase_auth version to the old version that works fine without androidX migration

Comment: Because flutter_firebase_ui 0.0.13 depends on firebase_auth ^0.6.2+1 and no versions of flutter_firebase_ui match >0.0.13 <0.1.0, flutter_firebase_ui ^0.0.13 requires firebase_auth ^0.6.2+1.
So, because store_manager_erp_next depends on both firebase_auth ^0.7.0 and flutter_firebase_ui ^0.0.13, version solving failed.

Comment: from https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: Try using these versions :
android_alarm_manager: 0.2.3
android_intent: 0.2.1
battery: 0.3.0
camera: 0.2.9+1
cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
cloud_functions: 0.0.5
connectivity: 0.3.2
device_info: 0.3.0
firebase_admob: 0.7.0
firebase_analytics: 1.1.0
firebase_auth: 0.7.0
firebase_core: 0.2.5+1
firebase_database: 1.0.5
firebase_dynamic_links: 0.1.1
firebase_messaging: 2.1.0
firebase_ml_vision: 0.2.1
firebase_performance: 0.0.8+1
firebase_remote_config: 0.0.6+1
firebase_storage: 1.0.4
google_maps_flutter: 0.1.0
google_sign_in: 3.2.4

Comment: image_picker: 0.4.12+1
local_auth: 0.3.1
package_info: 0.3.2+1
path_provider: 0.4.1
quick_actions: 0.2.2
sensors: 0.3.5
share: 0.5.3
shared_preferences: 0.4.3
url_launcher: 4.1.0+1
video_player: 0.9.0
webview_flutter: 0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

consult this link https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4650 and replace the version of your project with the corresponding version

Answer (score 0):

Try run pub get by omitting the version name of the package which is causing you the issue like this

```
firebase_storage:
```

This will get you out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can downgrade your google sign in version to stable one like

google_sign_in: ^4.5.9

to know the most stable one go to

https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in/versions

and choose latest one before beta version
pubspec.yaml file

environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
get: ^4.2.4
google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
firebase_core: "0.7.0"
firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"